# Как исправить проблему с отображением только первого элемента Recycler View из всех?

Tags: android, sql, recyclerview, room

Есть `RecyclerView`. В него добавляю 3 элемента с для хранения в SQL, однако отображается только первый, остальных на экране смартфона нет. Как это можно исправить?
Вот код Database, где происходит загрузка элементов

```
@Database(entities = {Categories.class}, version = 1)
```

public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

```
public abstract CategoriesDao categoriesDao();
private static volatile AppDatabase INSTANCE;

static AppDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        synchronized (AppDatabase.class) {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                // Create database here
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        AppDatabase.class, "mdb")
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .addCallback(sRoomDatabaseCallback)
                        .build();
            }
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

private static RoomDatabase.Callback sRoomDatabaseCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        // If you want to keep the data through app restarts,
        // comment out the following line.
        new PopulateDbAsync(INSTANCE).execute();
    }
};

/**
 * Populate the database in the background.
 * If you want to start with more words, just add them.
 */
private static class PopulateDbAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private final CategoriesDao mDao;

    PopulateDbAsync(AppDatabase db) {
        mDao = db.categoriesDao();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {
        // Start the app with a clean database every time.
        // Not needed if you only populate on creation.
        //mDao.deleteAll();

        Categories categories = new Categories("Title One","Subtitle One");
        mDao.insert(categories);
        categories = new Categories("Title Two","Subtitle Two");
        mDao.insert(categories);
        categories = new Categories("Title Three","Subtitle Three");
        mDao.insert(categories);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Вот код адаптера `RecyclerView`

```
public class CategoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoriesAdapter.CategoriesViewHolder> {

class CategoriesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final TextView title;
    private final TextView subtitle;
    //private final TextView number;

    private CategoriesViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        subtitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
        //number = itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
    }
}

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List<Categories> mCategories; // Cached copy of words

public CategoriesAdapter(Context context) { mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); }


@NonNull
@Override
public CategoriesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_test, parent, false);
    return new CategoriesViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategoriesViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (mCategories != null) {
        Categories current = mCategories.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(current.getTitle());
        holder.subtitle.setText(current.getSubtitle());
    } else {
        // Covers the case of data not being ready yet.
        holder.title.setText("No Title");
        holder.subtitle.setText("No Subtitle");
    }
}

public void setCategories(List<Categories> categories){
    mCategories = categories;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mCategories != null)
        return mCategories.size();
    else return 0;
}
}
```

Разметка с RecyclerView

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/categories_list"
    android:contentDescription="@string/cd_products_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Класс Categories

```
@Entity
public class Categories {

    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    public String title;
    public String subtitle;

    public Categories(@NonNull String title, String subtitle){
        this.title = title;
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getSubtitle() {
        return subtitle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Есть пара предположений: не правильно заданы размеры, привязки `RecyclerView` в разметке; выборка из базы производится одновременно с заполнением. Покажите разметку с `RecyclerView` и проверьте логами или под дебаггером содержимое списка в адаптере.

Comment: @woesss, добавил разметку

Comment: Мои предположения: Вы не добовляете в класс данные, а перезаписываете, проверте сколько строчек содержит база. Вы просите данные из базы не правильно(выборка неправильна)

Comment: To` Categories класс покажите

Comment: В лэйауте айтема ресайклера поставьте вместо android:layout_height="match_parent" нужно android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, добавил categories

Comment: @Valgaal, не решает проблему. Все равно 1 элемент, только теперь RecyclerView не в полный экран, а только в 1 элемент.

Comment: я не про ресайлер,  а про R.layout.item_test

Comment: Наверное в БД у вас таки всего один элемент записывается. Попробуйте `equals` `hashCode` методы в `Categories ` переопределить. И не использовать одну и ту же переменную при записи данных в БД.

Comment: добавьте логирование и выводите лог с размером списка перед тем как передавать его в список. Так вы узнаете,  в чем проблема, в БД или списке